# Split Huge CSV file into multiple files using Python

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, databricks

I have this huge CSV file (70 GB approx.) that I need to read using PySpark in Databricks, to create a Pyspark Dataframe. The file is saved in a Storage Account mounted to Databricks.

Now, I am not able to do so as it gives me an error:

*Driver is up but is not responsive, likely due to GC.*

As an alternative I thought about splitting the file into multiple CSV. Is there a way to do so easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say splitting a large CSV is fairly easy with Python.

I also recommend that for most tasks with CSV files (like, 99.999%) use a CSV-aware tool.  Suggestions like, "use this POSIX tool", will always struggle with headers, and rows that span mulitple lines because of quoted newlines.  So whether you use the following, or a tool like [GoCSV's split command](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv), use a tool that conforms to the CSV spec.  But if you know 100% your CSV doesn't have a header, and doesn't have multi-line rows, then you might be able to get away with a regular text processing tool.

To roll your own splitter in Python, you'll need some mechansim to create a new file and csv.writer after so many rows have been written to the previous file/writer.

I don't know how Pythonic the following is, but: I think it's fairly legible; and it works!

- The next_writer(header) function looks in the global space for the already-established csv.writer and its underlying output file.
- Every call to next_writer(...) closes the currently-open file (which flushes any buffered rows from the writer), creates **the next** file and its accompanying writer, and writes a header (if you need one).
- The main read-loop enumerates the reader so it knows which row (not *line*) it's on, and when the row number is a multiple of MAX_ROWS gets the next writer.

```py
import csv
import io

MAX_ROWS = 10

# "Initialize" f_out and writer as their respective types
f_out = io.StringIO("")
writer = csv.writer(f_out)
out_num = 0


def next_writer(header: list[str]):
    """Gets the next-numbered CSV writer; closes the previous file and flushes its writer."""
    global out_num
    global f_out
    global writer

    f_out.close()

    out_num += 1
    f_out = open(f"output_{out_num:03}.csv", "w", newline="")
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(header)


with open("input.csv", newline="") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    header = next(reader)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i % MAX_ROWS == 0:
            next_writer(header)

        writer.writerow(row)

f_out.close()  # close underlying file; flush writer
```

"Initializing" the out-file and writer seems a bit clunky, but, for my example that ensures we have the globally scoped writer (which next_writer(...) and the main read-loop need) and its underlying, numbered output file (for next_writer(...)).

I generated a CSV with 100 rows:

```
H____1,H____2
r001c1,r001c2
r002c1,r002c2
r003c1,r003c2
......,......
r098c1,r098c2
r099c1,r099c2
r100c1,r100c2
```

Running the above (with MAX_ROWS = 10) gives me 10 files, output_001.csv to output_010.csv (the format string `f"{out_num:03}"` pads the number with leading zeroes up to three places, to allow for 999 files).

Each file looks like:

```
output_001.csv
--------------
H____1,H____2
r001c1,r001c2
r002c1,r002c2
r003c1,r003c2
......,......

output_010.csv
--------------
H____1,H____2
......,......
r098c1,r098c2
r099c1,r099c2
r100c1,r100c2
```